# Dynamically nesting a list, and related comprehension/mapping to find indices of string match

Tags: python, python-2.7

The context of what I'm doing: I'm translating if/then/else statements between 2 languages via a Python script (2x for now, but may eventually upgrade to 3x). I have a function that takes the if/then/else statement from the original language and breaks it into a list of [if_clause,then_clause,else_clause]. The thing is, there may be (and often are) nested if statements in the then and/or else clauses. For example, I would pass a string like...

```
if (sim_time<=1242) then (new_tmaxF0740) else if (sim_time<=2338) then (new_tmaxF4170) else (new_tmaxF7100)
```

...to my function, and it would return the list...

```
['(sim_time<=1242)','(new_tmaxF0740)','if (sim_time<=2338) then (new_tmaxF4170) else (new_tmaxF7100)']
```

So, as you can see, in this case the else clause needs to be further broken up by running it again through the same function I used to generate the list, this time only passing the last list element to that function. I am going about this by testing the original string to see if there are more than 1 if statements contained (I already have the regex for this) and my thought is to use a loop to create nested lists within the original list, that might then look like...

[if_clause,then_clause,[if_clause, then_clause, else_clause]]

These can be nested any number of times/to any dimension. My plan so far is to write a loop that looks for the next nested if statement (using a regex), and reassigns the list index where the if statement is found to the resultant list from applying my if_extract() function to break up the statement.

I feel like list comprehension may not do this, because to find the indices, it seems like the list comprehension statement might have to dynamically change. Maybe better suited for map, but I'm not sure how to apply? I ultimately want to iterate through the loop to return the index of the next (however deeply nested) if statement so I can continue breaking them apart with my function.

Comment: Don't reinvent parsing for the fun of it, unless you're doing it for the fun of it. Even then, do it right.

Comment: i might bypass this loop structure and just change it to iterative string editing, but even then, i need regex

Comment: this *might* be simple enough for regex, but using regex to manipulate source code programatically is generally considered a red flag that you're doing it wrong. Is there really not a parser in python for the languages your working with? ex https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py/blob/master/examples/pyesprima.py

Comment: no, and i use "language" loosely - i'm translating equation layers from Stella. (actually, for the full story, i'm debugging someone else's code that is supposed to do so)

Comment: If it has a formal grammar, its a language and you can likely use a parser generator. Otherwise, yeah, regex. I'd still try to tokenize the expressions though.

Comment: the regex/translation needed is just for part of it - the larger context of the script i'm working on is generating from the equation layer a few (dependent) scripts in the destination language, and related input files from data that's "embedded" in the original equation layer. for the small part referenced in this question, indeed i think i'm going to avoid building the list structure and just "write as i go" with regex. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could call your function recursively.

```
def split_if_then_else(str):
    if check_if_if_in_string_function(str)
        if_clause, then_clause, else_clause = split_str_core_function(str)
        then_clause = split_if_then_else(str)
        return [if_clause, then_clause, else_clause]
    else:
        return str
```

I didn't test it since I don't know what functions you are using exactly, but I think something like this should work

Comment: I'll test and also add some detail above to the question to clarify my process

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't exactly what I needed because as you said I didn't provide the function, and I also reread and realized I could have framed the original ? better. Your suggestion to call the function recursively though led me the answer, to iterate using map() once the list became nested. Also, in your function to just return the string to the position if it didn't need to be split took me in a different (better) direction than I was headed